# Overriding one geom_line call for legend whilst retaining another

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to find a solution to this, but have been unsuccessful as I am not 100% sure what is causing the issue. As this is the last little thing keeping me from finsihing this project, any ideas would be sooo much appreciated!

My ggplot legend looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the `linetype` and `colour` are displayed combined, but there seems to be an additional solid line going through the linetypes, making them hard to read. I think this comes from an additional `geom_line` call to display the grey lines (raw data).

Here is my code minus the theme and labelling

```
ggplot(table_mean_a, mapping= aes(x = phase_bins, y = Mean)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = phase_bins, y = Mean, colour = cond_f))+
  geom_line(df_plotting_a, 
            mapping = aes(x=phase_bins, y = mean_change_to_base, group=interaction(ID, cond_f)),
            alpha = 0.3, size  =0.5, colour = "grey", inherit.aes = FALSE)+ 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="#666766", linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_errorbar(subset(table_mean_a, phase_bins!= "baseline"), 
                mapping=aes(ymin=Mean-SD, ymax=Mean+SD, colour = cond_f), 
                width=.4, size = 0.7)+
  geom_line(aes(group=as.numeric(cond_f),  colour = cond_f, linetype=cond_f), size = 1.2)+
  facet_wrap(sample~., labeller=labeller(sample = labels), ncol=2, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=apa)+
  labs(colour = "Condition:", linetype = "Condition:")+
     guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA, alpha = 1), byrow = TRUE))+   
     scale_x_discrete(labels= c("base", "stim1", "stim2", "recovery", "break"), drop = T, expand = c(0,0.25))+
     scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1,1), breaks = c(-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1), 
                     labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 1))+
     scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "81", "11", "5111"))
```

Here is the data

```
table_mean_a <-
structure(list(cond_f = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("artificial", "cry", "laugh", "babble"
), class = "factor"), phase_bins = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("pre", "baseline", "stim_bin1", 
"stim_bin2", "recovery", "break"), class = "factor"), age_group = c("adult", 
"adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", 
"adult", "adult"), sample = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("UKi", "UGi", "UKa"), class = "factor"), 
    Mean = c(0, -0.0616666666666667, -0.143333333333333, -0.0983333333333328, 
    -0.0231666666666662, 0, -0.0949999999999997, -0.1625, -0.113333333333333, 
    -0.155833333333333), SD = c(0, 0.154096119467973, 0.24172866718288, 
    0.423777912706934, 0.633257128379362, 0, 0.13934894565432, 
    0.248908435688157, 0.350921926972951, 0.677239732274149), 
    Min. = c(0, -0.366666666666667, -0.583333333333337, -0.716666666666667, 
    -0.98, 0, -0.466666666666665, -0.650000000000003, -0.783333333333337, 
    -1.96), Max. = c(0, 0.283333333333334, 0.383333333333336, 
    1.08333333333334, 1.72666666666667, 0, 0.199999999999996, 
    0.233333333333333, 0.5, 0.846666666666667), count = c(20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), groups = structure(list(cond_f = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("artificial", "cry", 
"laugh", "babble"), class = "factor"), phase_bins = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("pre", "baseline", 
"stim_bin1", "stim_bin2", "recovery", "break"), class = "factor"), 
    age_group = c("adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", 
    "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult"), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df_plotting_a <- 
structure(list(ID = structure(c(69L, 69L, 69L, 69L, 69L), .Label = c("UG201", 
"UG208", "UG209", "UG211", "UG215", "UG217", "UG219", "UG220", 
"UG221", "UG222", "UG228", "UG243", "UG247", "UG254", "UG268", 
"UG271", "UG272", "UG273", "UG274", "UG275", "UG280", "UG283", 
"UG284", "UG286", "UG297", "UG299", "UG308", "UG310", "UG315", 
"UG316", "UG330", "UG331", "UG334", "UG335", "UK103", "UK104", 
"UK105", "UK106", "UK107", "UK108", "UK110", "UK111", "UK112", 
"UK113", "UK115", "UK116", "UK117", "UK119", "UK122", "UK123", 
"UK130", "UK132", "UK135", "UK136", "UK138", "UK139", "UK140", 
"UK142", "UK145", "UK147", "UK150", "UK153", "UK155", "UK156", 
"UK159", "UK160", "UK162", "UK164", "UKA102", "UKA103", "UKA104", 
"UKA105", "UKA106", "UKA107", "UKA108", "UKA109", "UKA110", "UKA111", 
"UKA112", "UKA113", "UKA114", "UKA115", "UKA116", "UKA117", "UKA119", 
"UKA120", "UKA121", "UKA122"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("f", "m"), class = "factor"), trial = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    cond_f = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("artificial", 
    "cry", "laugh", "babble"), class = "factor"), age_group = c("adult", 
    "adult", "adult", "adult", "adult"), stimulus = structure(c(7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "b1", 
    "b2", "b3", "b4", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "l1", "l2", "l3", 
    "l4"), class = "factor"), phase_bins = structure(2:6, .Label = c("pre", 
    "baseline", "stim_bin1", "stim_bin2", "recovery", "break"
    ), class = "factor"), mean_change_to_base = c(0, -0.149999999999997, 
    -0.399999999999996, -0.299999999999996, -0.0733333333333306
    ), max_change_to_base = c(0, -0.333333333333329, -0.533333333333331, 
    -0.43333333333333, -0.333333333333329), sample = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("UKi", "UGi", "UKa"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), groups = structure(list(ID = structure(69L, .Label = c("UG201", 
"UG208", "UG209", "UG211", "UG215", "UG217", "UG219", "UG220", 
"UG221", "UG222", "UG228", "UG243", "UG247", "UG254", "UG268", 
"UG271", "UG272", "UG273", "UG274", "UG275", "UG280", "UG283", 
"UG284", "UG286", "UG297", "UG299", "UG308", "UG310", "UG315", 
"UG316", "UG330", "UG331", "UG334", "UG335", "UK103", "UK104", 
"UK105", "UK106", "UK107", "UK108", "UK110", "UK111", "UK112", 
"UK113", "UK115", "UK116", "UK117", "UK119", "UK122", "UK123", 
"UK130", "UK132", "UK135", "UK136", "UK138", "UK139", "UK140", 
"UK142", "UK145", "UK147", "UK150", "UK153", "UK155", "UK156", 
"UK159", "UK160", "UK162", "UK164", "UKA102", "UKA103", "UKA104", 
"UKA105", "UKA106", "UKA107", "UKA108", "UKA109", "UKA110", "UKA111", 
"UKA112", "UKA113", "UKA114", "UKA115", "UKA116", "UKA117", "UKA119", 
"UKA120", "UKA121", "UKA122"), class = "factor"), trial = structure(1L, .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), cond_f = structure(4L, .Label = c("artificial", 
"cry", "laugh", "babble"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:5), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legends from `geom_errorbar` and `geom_line` are overlapping together, therefore you see the solid line. You can use `show.legend = FALSE` in `geom_errorbar` to hide it.

Since some of your element used in `ggplot` is missing, here I only include the code for `geom_errorbar`.

```
geom_errorbar(subset(table_mean_a, phase_bins!= "baseline"), 
                mapping=aes(ymin=Mean-SD, ymax=Mean+SD, colour = cond_f), 
                width=.4, size = 0.7, show.legend = F)
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much! I was thinking there must be an easy fix, but this is even more straight forward than I though